# What is the dish of meat or fish cooked in very little liquid like soy source until the meat/fish becomes sticky?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

I want to cook this dish

-fish/ meat/ chicken/ beef etc was cut into pieces

-put the pieces into a pot

-pour just a little oil in the pot

-pour some Asian soy sauce or fish sauce in (I don't pour water in)

-cook it slowly in low or medium temperature until the meat/fish/beef/chicken etc becomes sticky like this

This is a **fish stew/soup/casserole ...???**

[image]

Or

This is a meat **stew/soup/casserole ...???**

[image]

I don't know which word I should use!!

For example, **a meat/fish/chicken... stew/soup/casserole...**

or "**braised meat/fish/chicken...**"?

**What do you say this dish in everyday English?**

Comment: You should know better to eliminate "soup" from the options. Soup can be thick but it is never eaten with a fork or with chopsticks.

Comment: It sounds like what my Chinese cookbooks call 'red-cooked' or 'red-braised' meat. I suppose the nearest equivalent in European cookery would be 'braised'.A stew/casserole has plenty of liquid so that the food doesn't dry out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like "teriyaki". The top certainly looks like a salmon teriyaki. The sauce is slightly sweet, and gets shiny when reduced.

Food names are very culturally specific and the names for specific dishes get borrowed from one language or another.  This particular borrowing comes from Japanese, but you will find that "chow mein", "bhuna" "coq-au-vin" and "sauerkraut" are all English words (borrowed from around the world)